# Navigate to the Documents Tab

Tags: document

I'm trying to "navigate to the documents tab" to add a image file to use as an application logo.  Try as I might, I can't find the documents tab.  Can someone give me step-by-step instructions ?

I'm using the Developer Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on + Sign at end of all tabs visible to you , this will take you to all tabs sorted alphabetically, search for document.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a little bit of programming skill and can use `Execute Anonymous`, you can also discover the `Tab` url dynamically using the `Document` object's `Key Prefix`. In this case, the prefix is `015`, so you would do:

> https://**myInstance**.salesforce.com/015/o

You can find the key prefix by doing:

```
system.debug(SObjectType.Document.getKeyPrefix());
```

This approach can be useful when the `Tab` is not visible for some reason, but it's still there.

Comment: too complicated for this question

Comment: I understand that OP is unlikely to take this approach, but it has been very useful to me in the past and seemed worth sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Its just under "Show All Tabs" which is the "+" sign on your Home Tab when you login.

Also as mentioned above Type https://**DevInstance**.salesforce.com/015/o in address bar once you logged in will directly redirect to "Documents Tab".

Comment: How is this remotely different from either of the already posted answers?

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND IT!

For some reason the documents tab (Object) in my playground instance is only showing up in Salesforce Classic. Try switching to CLASSIC and then looking for documents.